# Related Questions - How To Tell If They've Been Answered

Tags: feature-request

Alongside each question there's a list of related questions, which are often relevant and interesting. For some reason, their scores appear in grey boxes even if the questions have been answered. Surely it would be more helpful if they were colour coded as happens elsewhere on the site?

I see the advantages as follows

1. If you've just answered a question on a topic, you probably know something about it. Therefore you're probably well positioned to answer related unanswered questions. If would be really useful to see at a glance whether there are any!
2. If you've just asked or read a question, you might be interested in reading round the subject. Therefore you'll probably want to check out other answered questions on the same topic. Hence the need for this feature.

I imagine it wouldn't be very hard to implement, given that the code must exist elsewhere on the site. Perhaps upvote this if you think it would be useful, and someone can escalate it as a feature request to SE?

Comment: A similar question was proposed [once on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195149/), but it doesn't seem to have been completed/noticed by SE team.

Comment: Ah - thanks for the link. Given that Math.SE has it, maybe if we get enough upvotes on this we can create some social pressure for them to implement it. From the looks of things it would only take 0.5s to do!